# recursive function for upheap method(how can i write this non-recursive method into recursive)

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, heap

```
 protected void up-heap(int j) {
while (j > 1) {            // continue until reaching root (or break)
  int p = parent(j);
  if (compare(heap.get(j), heap.get(p)) >= 1) break; // heap property verified
  swap(j, p);
  j = p;                                // continue from the parent's location
}}
```

how to write this non-recursive code into recursive using java.i am not getting how to convert this into recursive.i tried many websites but i din't got the answer

Comment: Is this question about c++ or java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is to rewrite the `while` loop into recursive method calls. This is very simple:

```
protected void upHeap(int j) {
  if (j <= 1) //this handles the condition of the original while loop
    return;
  int p = parent(j);
  if (compare(heap.get(j), heap.get(p)) >= 1) 
    return; // this handles the break from the while loop
  swap(j, p);
  upHeap(p); // the recursive method call, replacing j with p
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the swap change j -> p and p -> j? Shouldn't you call upHeap on j again as that now has all of p's characteristics?

Comment: Ah, unless you only swapped the data and left the parent/children the same...